# ¿Como puedo ordenar nombres en orden alfabético utilizando un treeset en java?

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un pequeño programa el cual pido varios datos, pero en los datos de tipo string (Apellidos) tengo que ordenarlos alfabéticamente, los apellidos los voy guardando utilizando un treeset, pero no encuentro la forma de ordenarlos alfabéticamente, me podrían dar alguna recomendación de como poder hacerlo.
fragmentos del Bodigo:

aqui es donde creo mi treeset para los apellidos.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    Hashtable<String, String> claveValor = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    TreeSet <String> Apellidos = new TreeSet<String>();
    TreeSet <String> Pais = new TreeSet<String>();
```

en esta parte es como le agrego los apellidos a mis treeset:

```
System.out.println("Apellido: ");
apellido = entrada.next();
Apellidos.add(apellido);
```

asi se ven los apellidos cuando los mando a mostrar:

```
[PALACIOS]
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el paquete de Collections puedes hacerlo tan simple como :

```
Collections.sort(Apellidos)
```

pero antes tienes que convertir tu ***TreeSet*** a una ***List*** , ya que ***Collections.sort*** recibe una Lista.

```
List<String> listApellidos = new ArrayList<String> (Apellidos);
Collections.sort(listApellidos)
```

Con esto te ordena alfabéticamente , pero recuerda hacer el sort cuando ya añadas todos los nombres.

Si quieres recuperar el treeSet, tienes que pasar la lista ordenada cuando creas el  nuevo treeset , tienes que hacer :

```
 TreeSet<String> Apellidos2 = new TreeSet<String>(listApellidos);
```

Comment: entocnes tendria que eliminar mi treeset y los apellidos pasarlos a una lista (¿Un arrayList?)

Comment: Te acabo de agregar , una nueva línea de código para recuperar el treeSet ya ordenado

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, en verdad lo agradezco.

Comment: Si te ha servido vota la respuesta como buena